# Group by a few columns including MAX() to limit rows but display columns not in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm outputting sp_whoisactive to a log table every 5 minutes and want to aggregate columns such as elapsed time or cpu.  My best chance for unique record is session_id, login_time, login_name and I want the MAX(collection_time) for each unique record.

My question is how do you do this in one query?

I tried all kind of variations and could never get the desired output.  I ended up doing 2 steps 1) the group by to a ##Temp table and 2) then joining the ##temp to the log table to get the all the columns I wanted in the report.

Step 1 query:

```
    enter code hereIF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE ##TEMP END
        SELECT *
            INTO ##TEMP
            FROM (
select distinct Session_id, login_name, login_time, max(collection_time) as MaxCollection
from [MyDB].[DBA].[WhoIsActive]
group by login_name,  session_id, login_time
                ) AS X
```

Step 2 query:

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATETIME, @today DATETIME
SET @yesterday = DATEADD(hh,12,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()-1),0))
SET @today = DATEADD(hh,11,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()-0),0))

SELECT 
       tt.[session_id]
      ,tt.[tasks]
      ,tt.[login_time]
      ,tt.[login_name]
      ,tt.[start_time]
      ,tt.[collection_time]      
      ,tt.[dd hh:mm:ss.mss] as ElapsedTime
      ,(Substring(tt.[dd hh:mm:ss.mss],1,2) * 86400) + (Substring(tt.[dd hh:mm:ss.mss],4,2) * 3600) + (Substring(tt.[dd hh:mm:ss.mss],7,2) * 60) + (Substring(tt.[dd hh:mm:ss.mss],10,2)) as totalseconds
      ,tt.[host_name]
      ,tt.[status]
      ,tt.[CPU]
      ,tt.[program_name]

FROM [MyDB].[DBA].[WhoIsActive] tt
right JOIN ##TEMP kk
on tt.session_id = kk.session_id and tt.collection_time = kk.MaxCollection
--where kk.start_time between @yesterday and @today --and kk.login_name like '%ETL%'
order by tt.login_name asc, tt.session_id asc, login_time desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My best chance for unique record is `session_id`, `login_time`, `login_name` and I want the `MAX(collection_time)` for each unique record.

If you just want the max collection time for each tuple, then use aggregation:

```
select session_id, login_time, login_name, max(collection_time) max_collection_time
from whoisactive
group by session_id, login_time, login_name
```

On the other hand, if you want the *entire* corresponding rows, then one option is `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select w.*,
        row_number() over(partition by session_id, login_time, login_name order by collection_time desc) rn
    from whoisactive w
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: GMB perhaps I didn't phrase my question well.  For each distinct tuple I want only the one row that contains MAX(collection_time) and any or all columns as may be requested.

Each tuple may have many rows because a job may run for an hour or two and I'm collecting a status every 5 minutes.  I just want the last collection.  Hope this explains better.

Comment: when you said "if you want the entire corresponding rows" instead of columns I interpreted it to mean what it said but when I run it, it appears to do what I want.  Can't say I've ever used row_number() over(partition so I'll have to read up on it. 

Since I didn't have login_time in my table I had to rebuild and have only small set of data to test.  This may be my answer.